# Difficulty Converting .png to CSS Sprite

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to convert this Star Wars image file to Sprite so that I can use several of the individual drawings. However, it seems that I can only use Sprite if the background is not completely white, but rather a checkered white-grey pattern (not sure why this is?). Is there a way to convert the file into a Sprite image? I attempted ZeroSprites.com, but it still gave me the white background; I'd like to be able to render each of the drawings without the white background so that the characters' outlines blend in smoothly into my main background.

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: A white-grey pattern is a way to indicate that the image is transparent, i.e. there is no background colour.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this from an image like the above?

Comment: What do u mean by white-gray background and how do you know your image has background? please simply have your image on a simple html with body having background-color of green and see if your image is transparent or not

Answer (score 1):

It's best if you have the images as vector and export it as .png

Removing white background is possible but it won't be as good as the original.

You can follow this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV38L4c4JKY

Here's the same image as png:
http://cubeupload.com/im/cSEdTC.png